# Sencha Cmd [ERR] no !/ in spec

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

```
os: win 10
node: 14.17.6
npm: 6.14.15
ext-gen: 7.4
commercial license
```

this is a fresh install, so:

1. logged into npm
2. installed ext-gen
3. created an app stub via ext-gen app -a -t universalmodern -n AppName
4. tried to launch it via npm start (npm run dev:desktop)

Console prints the following and then stops:

```
Sencha Cmd v7.4.0.45 [ERR] no !/ in spec
```

with verbose output I also get:

```
-verbose: on close: 321
-verbose: onBuildDone
```

Luckily, I can start my app with `sencha app watch`, but obviously hoped for the node tools to behave properly.

Ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I made it work...  The problem is a # char in my project path. when I change the folder name it works again :) so my local specifics are the root cause of the problem. still a more descriptive err msg would come in handy